# rerender in visualforce not working when integrated with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, salesforce

I have used Twitter Bootstrap in my visualforce page. The User interface looks pretty cool. 
But the problem I'm facing that apex:CommandButtons are not working. After investigating further, I realized that it is throwing some javascript exception when using rerender attribute in command buttons.

JavaScript error states as : "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'indexOf' ".

Solution: add namespace - http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2015/3/23/namespacing-bootstrap-from-square-one

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am trying to implement bootstrap instead of apex components (still using commandbuttons though)...essentially I want to replace apex standard styles with bootstrap tables - I need to rerender the bootstrap table and I don't yet know how .

Comment: You should use custom HTML instead of any visualforce components. 
For interacting with Apex controller, use JavaScript Remoting.
Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Thanks, your right.  I ended up using VisualStrap to get the bootstrap components alongside Datatables jquery plugin

Comment: That's awesome, it's bit slow when you have large dataset in datatables, like say more than 15-20k

Comment: Ah, I'm well under that (actually limiting the web service to returning 200 at most.  I still need to look a Javascript Remoting as I need to save the values from the table to the controller/salesforce...thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this version of Bootstrap and it worked in all cases
https://github.com/azhar-js/bootstrap-force

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will go and have a look at it and would revert with the result.